# preview Image blank and no descritpion when shraing news on linkedin

Tags: image, linkedin-api, sharing

When i share any articles on linkedin from www.ekilium.fr, title preview images are blank and descprition/title are empty.

For instance the home page is validated by google microformat test page with 0 errors, and facebook test page. The share works on google+, twitter,facebook, viadeo... and not on linkedin.

I have checked the prescence of og: tags according to https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin
i ve found no error

I've made a www.ekilium.fr/test.html page with the minimum structure and tags for test it doesn't work either.

It does not seem to be an website technical issue and I could not understand what happens...

Any help will be appreciated.
thx

Comment: I've got the exact same problem! Even tested the exact same HTML on a different server and it seems to work. We are not blocking linkedin, but maybe the other way around?

Comment: Have you said that If you put the same page on another site it works ? My site is on an ovh host and the problem seems to happend til the host offers free https support (even if i did not activated it). Is there a way that this double way to access may introduce problems.